# Vectorized dataframe look-up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, lookup

I have two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A']], columns=['Mon', 'Tues'])

    Mon Tues
0   A   B
1   B   A

lookup = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]], index=['A', 'B'], columns=df.columns)

    Mon Tues
A   0   1
B   2   3
```

For each day, for each key in the first dataframe, I would like to look up its value in the second dataframe. This is one way to do it:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    output[col] = df[col].map(lookup[col])

    Mon Tues
0   0   3
1   2   1
```

Is there a way to get the same answer without the explicit loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to exchange the values:

```
>>> df.replace(lookup)
   Mon  Tues
0    0     3
1    2     1
```

When passed to the `replace` method, DataFrames are treated similarly to nested dictionaries. For each column label, the column's values are mapped  to the correspondingly indexed value in the lookup DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that each column data in `df` is a random order of the `lookup.index` and that `lookup.index` is in sorted order. So, going with it, here's a NumPy based vectorized solution, specifically using its [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
idx = np.argsort(df.values,1)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(lookup.values[idx,np.arange(idx.shape[1])],columns=df.columns)
```

Sample output -

```
In [41]: idx = np.argsort(df.values,1)

In [42]: pd.DataFrame(lookup.values[idx,np.arange(idx.shape[1])],columns=df.columns)
Out[42]: 
   Mon  Tues
0    0     3
1    2     1
```

---

If `lookup.index` is not in sorted order, we need to do some additional work -

```
sidx = lookup.index.argsort()
arr_out = lookup.values[idx,np.arange(idx.shape[1])][sidx]
```